# ScrollView. Непонятная штука при прокрутке

Tags: java, android-studio, scrollview

как убрать тень(не знаю как она называется) у ScrollView, которая появляется при достижении конца у ScrollView? Вот фото: [image: Изображение]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android:overScrollMode="never"

или

android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"